# atl activex control using opengl (C++)

Tags: opengl, activex, atl

Has anyone tried to create ATL activex control using OpenGL? If so please give me some guidance on how to develop it.

How do we update the scene on mouse events (for rotation of object)?
How do we add object to scene on button click, without disturbing the objects on the scene?

Comment: I did, but it has been much more than 10 years, and I wish I could remember more of it. I don't recall any major obstacles. I believe you create a child window, and then set up the whole pixelformat/context stuff the same way you do for a regular window before using it for OpenGL rendering. Once you got that all set up, OpenGL rendering should work as usual. I don't recall how to wire up the mouse events, but that should be well documented. A quick search brings up for example this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985028.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2961/How-to-add-OpenGL-support-to-ATL-controls. I am able to Create context using opengl. But i dont know how to setup mouse/button events to update scene.